# SQL Order random rows based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, oracle9i

How to sort this table in Oracle9:

```
START | END | VALUE
  A   |  F  |   1
  D   |  H  |   9
  F   |  C  |   8
  C   |  D  |  12
```

To make it look like this?:

```
START | END | VALUE
   A  |  F  |   1
   F  |  C  |  12
   C  |  D  |   8
   D  |  H  |   9
```

Goal is to start every next row with the end from the previous row.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY "value"`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Should have used another value example. Will edit it right away

Comment: Is it always a chain like you are showing or can there be duplicates (two records having the same start or end)? Can there be several rows having no matching follower?

Comment: Is the data always continuously ? or there can be gaps?

Comment: There can never be a gap between START and END. The data will ultimately always return back. It's kinda like a circle. Duplicates aren't possible and 2 records can never have the same start or end

Comment: And the first one is always A or the lowest letter?

Comment: Can be any letter. But ultimately there will be something like Start = K, End = A. Which will complete the circle

Comment: A cycle! So results can start with any record? It doesn't matter which?

Comment: That sounds tricky.. how do we know where to start

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with the order by clause alone, as it would have to find the record without a predecessor first, then find the next record comparing end and start column of the two records etc. This is an iterative process for which you need a recursive query.

That recursive query would find the first record, then the next and so on, giving them sequence numbers. Then you'd use the result and order by those generated numbers.

Here is how to do it in standard SQL. This is supported from Oracle 11g onwards only, however. In Oracle 9 you'll have to use `CONNECT BY` with which I am not familiar. Hopefully you or someone else can convert the query for you:

```
with chain(startkey, endkey, value, pos) as
(
  select startkey, endkey, value, 1 as pos 
  from mytable
  where not exists (select * from mytable prev where prev.endkey = mytable.startkey)
  union all
  select mytable.startkey, mytable.endkey, mytable.value, chain.pos + 1 as pos 
  from chain 
  join mytable on mytable.startkey = chain.endkey
)
select startkey, endkey, value
from chain
order by pos;
```

UPDATE: As you say the data is cyclic, you'd have to change above query so as to start with an arbitrarily chosen row and stop when through:

```
with chain(startkey, endkey, value, pos) as
(
  select startkey, endkey, value, 1 as pos 
  from mytable
  where rownum = 1
  union all
  select mytable.startkey, mytable.endkey, mytable.value, chain.pos + 1 as pos 
  from chain 
  join mytable on mytable.startkey = chain.endkey
)
cycle startkey set cycle to 1 default 0
select startkey, endkey, value
from chain
where cycle = 0
order by pos;
```